# Change the Text on an Android Tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have an Android app with 3 tabs in a TabHost (text labels, no images). I set up the tabs like so:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AnnouncementsActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("news").setIndicator("News").setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

I start up a background thread to fetch announcements from my server and I want to update the text label on the tab to tell the user how many new announcements there are. For example, I want to change the text on the Tab to "News (3)". How can I access and change the text label on the tab?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the code demonstrated [here](http://www.anddev.org/regarding_tabhost-t1793.html), see at the end of the code there is hacky way to get the textView.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have a problem getting access to the TabHost, my problem is that I can't find anything in the TabHost that allows me to change the text on the tab. How do I change the text once I have the TabHost reference?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. You're right, it is really hackish and I'm not sure why there isn't an easier way, but it is working for me so it'll do for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
tv.setText("New Tab Text");
```

Where `android.R.id.title` is System generated, just change **ChildIndex** and **Text** according to your need

Comment: For me it gives null pointer exception for the textView. Can you please explain this for me?

Comment: @ParthibanM please see my post below as a possible solution to your null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

For a later version of android (5.1), this worked for me:

Please note this example only changes the first tab's text. It would not be too difficult to adjust for an arbitrary tab.

```
FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
AppCompatTextView tv = null;
RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < parentLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {

    View tempView = parentLayout.getChildAt(i);

    if (tempView instanceof AppCompatTextView) {
        tv = (AppCompatTextView)tempView;
    }
}

if (tv != null) {
    tv.setText("Your updated text goes here");
}
```

All I did was run it through the debugger and figure out the hierarchy. I couldn't get the android.R.id.title to work as the text view is now referenced by a different id. Anyways, it's also now an AppCompatTextView instead of a plain old TextView.

Again, this is non-optimal, but gets the desired result for more recent versions of android.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I need to change the text of TabHost and I solved the problem  by using the following code.

Please excuse my English, I'm Brazilian and I'm still learning.
I hope to help someone who has the same problem.

```
TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabDetail);
    host.setup();

    //Tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Details");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 2
    spec = host.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Comments");
    host.addTab(spec);
```